# Summation of squared x_i if summation of x_i is 1

Tags: variance, mean, sum, inequality

How to prove "If $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=1$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2>1/n$"? 
I'm thinking about $Var(x_i)=E(x_i^2)-[E(x_i)]^2=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2-1/n^2\ge0$. Is that correct?

Comment: Can you please add the [tag:self-study] tag and read its wiki?

Comment: There is a pleasant geometrical interpretation: *No point on the hyperplane passing through the point $P=(1/n, 1/n,\ldots, 1/n)$ with normal direction $nP=(1,1,\ldots, 1)$ lies in the interior of the origin-centered ball of squared radius $|P|^2 = 1/n^2 + \cdots 1/n^2 = 1/n.$*  The proof is that this hyperplane is (obviously) tangent to the boundary of that ball, because its normal vector is parallel to the radius vector at one point of intersection ($P$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try writing variance as 
$$
Var(x_i)=E(x^2_i)−[E(x_i)]^2 
$$

substitute $$[E(x_i)]^2 = 1/n^2 $$

$$
1/n\Sigma (x_i - \bar x)^2 = 1/n\Sigma x_i^2 - 1/n^2
$$

from there

$$
1/n\Sigma x_i^2 = 1/n\Sigma(x_i - \bar x)^2 +  1/n^2)
$$

$$
 \Sigma x_i^2 = (\Sigma(x_i - \bar x)^2 +  1/n)
$$

which is the same as

$$
\Sigma x_i^2 = (\Sigma(x_i - \bar x)^2 +  1/n)
$$

or
$$
\Sigma x_i^2 = n*Var(x_i) + 1/n
$$

Since variance and n are greater than 0

$$
 n*Var(x_i) + 1/n > 1/n
$$

$$
\Sigma x_i^2 > 1/n
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Can you calculate the (arithmetic) mean of the $x_i$, $\bar{x}=\frac1{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$?  Then write $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n\left( (x_i-\bar{x})+ \bar{x}\right)^2$ and you should be able to conclude.